# How to control JPanel setSize when using BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing

I have a `ComponentListener` for the main `JFrame` that sends an event when it is resized but by the time the event is fired, the `Jpanel` has already been resized.

```
public class Test implements ComponentListener {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Test() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.addComponentListener(this);

        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test test = new Test();
                    test.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println(frame.getSize() + " : " + panel.getSize());
        frame.revalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
}
```

How do I control `JPanel setSize` during a `JFrame` resize?

**Edit:** I understand `BorderLayout` sets components to fill the border. How does it set the size of the component? Is it calling `setSize`? if yes, why an overridden setSize called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control a components size directly when it is added to a container under a LayoutManager's control. That defeats the purpose of using a layout manager.

If you want to be *notified* when a components size has changed, add a ComponentListener to the component (not the container).

Comment: I changed the ComponentListener from the JFrame to the JPanel and that proved to be more inline with what I was expecting.

Comment: @Aboutblank Regarding the question why an overwritten setSize() is not called, its much more likely a LayoutManager calls a setBounds()-method since it not only controls size but also placement. But there is *no specification* which method the LayoutManager has to use, so it can use any on the Component methods it find the most suitable for its job.

Comment: thanks for that info, that was kinda what I was trying to find out.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it calling setSize?

Layout manager use getPreferredSize(), getMinimumSize() and getMaximum() size as hints. The layout manager and use or ignore these hints. When you add a component to the CENTER of the BorderLayout all the hints are ignored and the component is sized to the space available. So, yes, the layout manager will invoke the setSize() (and setLocation) methods of a component. You should not invoke the setSize() method directly

> why isn't my overridden setSize called?

You did not `override` the setSize() method. When you execute your code you `invoked` the setSize() method. Then later the layout manager is invoked when the frame is packed() and the layout manager will invoke the setSize() method on the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resize a component in a BorderLayout if it's constraint is BorderLayout.CENTER.
The component takes automatically all the available space.

More informations : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html